# How do I stop my robot after it drives forward over a black band?

Tags: python

I am using a coloured back ground made up of bands in the order red, white, green, white, blue, white, black, white.  I want the robot to stop after it drives forward over the black band.

%%sim_magic_preloaded --background Grey_bands -R

## Program to count the bands aloud

## Start the robot moving

tank_drive.on(SpeedPercent(15), SpeedPercent(15))

## Initial count value

count = 0

## Initial sensor reading

previous_value = colorLeft.reflected_light_intensity_pc

## Create a loop

while True:

```
# Check current sensor reading
current_value = colorLeft.reflected_light_intensity_pc

# Test when the robot has entered a band
if previous_value==100 and current_value < 100:
    # When on a new band:
    # - increase the count
    count = count + 1
    # - display the count in the output window
    print(count)
    # - say the count aloud
    say(str(count))

# Update previous sensor reading
previous_value = current_value
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After `say(str(count))` you could add.

```
if count > 5:
    # Stop the robot moving
    tank_drive.on(SpeedPercent(0), SpeedPercent(0))
```

Obviously I don't know how many bands you have so modify `5` to the number you want.